# How to forward vnc for multiple hops

Tags: linux, forwarding, vnc

I have 2 machines Intrim and Remote. I have to go through Intrim to get to Remote. Normally I just do this:

```
ssh -X Intrim #now I'm in Intrim
ssh -X Remote
```

And I just open up things with the forwarded x. But vnc is way better. How can I do this with vnc?

A perfect solution would let me just vnc to Intrim and automatically see my Remote desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your workstation:

```
$ ssh -L5900:localhost:5900 user@interim.host
```

From `interim.host`:

```
$ ssh -L5900:localhost:5900 user@remote.host
```

Then connect your local VNC client to `localhost:5900`.